# apollo server receive empty object from apollo upload client

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

I using `apollo server` and `apollo upload client`.

this is my client code to send file :

```
const updateMarketing = gql`
    mutation UpdateMarketing(
        $file1: Upload
        $file2: Upload
        $file3: Upload
        $payload: MarketingInput!
    ) {
        updateMarketing(
            file1: $file1
            file2: $file2
            file3: $file3
            payload: $payload
        ) {
            isSuccess
            error
            data
        }
    }
`;
```

and this code for mutation :

```
<Mutation mutation={updateMarketing}>
                        {(
                            updateMarketing,
                            { data, loading, error }
                        ) => (
                            <div>
                                <form
                                    onSubmit={e => {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        console.log(e.target.file1.files[0]);
                                        updateWmsSkuTicketMarketing({
                                            variables: {
                                                file1: e.target.file1.files[0],
                                                file2: e.target.file2.files[0],
                                                file3: e.target.file3.files[0],
                                                payload: {
                                                    id: e.target.id.value,
                                                    jobId: e.target.jobId.value
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        id="id"
                                        name="id"
                                        placeholder="id"
                                    />
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        id="jobId"
                                        name="jobId"
                                        placeholder="job id"
                                    />
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        id="file1"
                                        name="file1"
                                    />
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        id="file2"
                                        name="file2"
                                    />
                                    <br />
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        id="file3"
                                        name="file3"
                                    />
                                    <br />
                                    <button type="submit">
                                        update  marketing
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                {loading && (
                                    <div>Updating for marketing</div>
                                )}
                                {data && (
                                    <div>
                                        Update  markting Proccess
                                        is finished
                                    </div>
                                )}
                                {error && (
                                    <div>
                                        Error update marketing…
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Mutation>
```

on server I tried to get the file :

```
const updateMarketing = ({ payload, token, file1, file2, file3 }) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {

                console.log(file1, payload);
                file1
                    .then(({ stream, filename }) => {
                         //get stream
                     });
            }
            // catch
```

but it error : `file1.then is not a function`

and `console.log(file1)` on server : `{}`

may be I wrong in client, but I dont find it.

please help me, where I wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Does `updateMarketing` is the resolver?

Your mutation args are in second resolver function argument

In example of `apollo upload client`, it use second argument to get files too.

See [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers#resolver-function-signature)

And the [example](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-examples/blob/master/api/resolvers.mjs#L55)